# How to abort wget after getting N times file not found?

Tags: wget

I try to grab pictures from few galleries of some site. I do not know how many files are there, but I know the files are continuous named. So I use a regex like that:

```
wget http://example.org/some_path_to_gallery_x/DSC{0001..9999}.jpg
```

It is still possible that some files are missing, but if there are more than 10 or N missing files in a row the gallery obviously reaches the end. How to abort `wget` at that moment to avoid unnecessary traffic and run time so I can switch to another gallery path?

Till now I have only a for loop, a counter and `wget` exit code handling in mind. But I am to weak in BASH for it. Or may be there is some magic `wget` keys for it?

**UPD:** a BASH script for it.

```
    #!/bin/bash

    G_PATH=$1
    MAX_MISSING=10
    C_ABORT=$MAX_MISSING

    for i in {0001..9999}
      do
      wget 'http://example.org/'"${G_PATH}"/DSC${i}.jpg 2>/dev/null
      if [ $? -eq 0 ]
      then
        C_ABORT=$MAX_MISSING
      else
        C_ABORT=$((C_ABORT-1))
        if [ $C_ABORT -eq 0 ]
        then
          echo break at DSC$i.jpg
          break
        else
          echo DSC$i.jpg is missing
        fi
      fi
    done
```

Comment: Show us your code (even if weak). Try to keep a second counter (set to 0 on new gallery), that indicates how many failures in a row (based on exit value of `wget`: set to 0 on success, increment on failure)

Comment: Sorry, I failed the formatting, but it seens like I could solve the problem by myself.
Here some code http://pastebin.com/HkCPv5RP

Comment: And you cannot do much formatting in comments, that is on purpose.

Comment: @Anthon, why C_ABORT should be set to MAX_MISSING if loop reaches 9999? MAX_MISSING is a threshold after then script stops.

Comment: Sorry, I misread that (blame it on the layout) as being the retry-count for a single item, and then gave the wrong advice.